# Setting System.Drawing.Color through .NET COM Interop

Tags: .net, python, com, interop, aspose

I am trying to use Aspose.Words library through COM Interop. There is one critical problem: I cannot set color. It is supposed to work by assigning to DocumentBuilder.Font.Color, but when I try to do it I get OLE error 0x80131509. My problem is pretty much like [this one](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/81588/font.color/showthread.aspx#81588).

update:

Code Sample:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Doc = Dispatch("Aspose.Words.Document")
Builder = Dispatch("Aspose.Words.DocumentBuilder")
Builder.Document = Doc
print Builder.Font.Size
print Builder.Font.Color
```

Result:

```
12.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aaa.py", line 6, in <module>
    print Builder.Font.Color
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 501, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2146233079, 'OLE error 0x80131509', None, None)
```

Using something like Font.Color = 0xff0000 fails with same error message

While this code works ok:

```
using Aspose.Words;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
            builder.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            builder.Write("aaa");
            doc.Save("c:\\1.doc");
        }
    }
}
```

So it looks like COM Interop problem.

Comment: show us a little piece of code of what you are doing, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check the answer provided here:
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/240901/create-a-pivot-table-from-multiple-data-ranges.aspx
I think, this approach should help you to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thansk for answer. Looks like that it will be possible to create generic function like SetColor(object, propertyname, color) using .NET Reflection.